# How to add a personalized title bar in Jetpack Compose for Desktop

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How do I add a personalized title bar in Jetpack Compose for Desktop app that includes maximize, minimize, and close buttons with its appropriate functionalities.

I've tried to do something like

```
import androidx.compose.desktop.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntSize
import androidx.compose.ui.window.WindowPlacement
import androidx.compose.ui.window.application
import androidx.compose.ui.window.rememberWindowState
import java.awt.Window
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Close
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier


@Composable
fun TitleBar(
    modifier: Modifier =Modifier,
    onCloseClick: () -> Unit,
    onMinimizeClick: () -> Unit,
    onMaximizeClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(modifier) {
        Icon(Icons.Default.Minimize, contentDescription = "Minimize", onClick = onMinimizeClick)
        Icon(Icons.Default.Maximize, contentDescription = "Maximize", onClick = onMaximizeClick)
        Icon(Icons.Default.Close, contentDescription = "Close", onClick = onCloseClick)
    }
}

fun main() = application {
    Window(
        title = "TestApp",
        size = IntSize(860, 640),
        state = rememberWindowState(
            placement = WindowPlacement.Floating
        )
    ) {
        val windowState = rememberWindowState()
        val isMaximized = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        TitleBar(
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Gray),
            onCloseClick = { windowState.close() },
            onMinimizeClick = { windowState.minimize() },
            onMaximizeClick = {
                if (isMaximized.value) {
                    windowState.restore()
                } else {
                    windowState.maximize()
                } 
                        isMaximized.value = !isMaximized.value
            }
        )

    }
}
```

But getting a lot of errors starting from the line `Icon(Icons.Default.Minimize, contentDescription = "Minimize", onClick = onMinimizeClick)` and so on...

[image]

I'm totally new to Jetpack Compose and Kotlin so there is probably some silly mistakes in there.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your question about the title bar and functionality, or just about "why can't I resolve the icons"? If it's the latter, did you try adding a dependency on `material-icons-extended`?

Comment: @Jorn Both, I guess... BTW do I add the dependency like `implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.4.3")` ?

Comment: Yes, although it's nicer to write using the compose plugin: `implementation(compose.materialIconsExtended)`

Comment: @Jorn Unfortunately the errors still remain..

Comment: Maybe those icons are too new and not included in your Compose version yet? I've seen issues like that before. But I don't think the [icon library](https://fonts.google.com/icons) shows that information.

Comment: Can I use an *.ico file in that case? how ? What about the errors `Unresolved reference: close, Unresolved reference: minimize ....`, BTW, I've also got an error in the build `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.`